# Oozie shell action - The action is completed successfully , but the workflow is getting killed.Shell action has spark submit

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to execute an shell action of oozie. The shell has spark-submit command and parameters. The spark is getting completed successfully , the corresponding oozie mapreduce task is also getting completed successfully ,but the workflow gets killed . 
The next iteration of the workflow is not happening , it gets killed immediately after the oozie shell action(with spark submit).
It was working , but sometimes gives this issue.

Comment: Please post the oozie work flow for better clarity

Comment: I got it sorted out , it was happening because of a special character present in the next line of the spark submit command. The shell, after completing the spark submit was trying to interpret the special character and failing.
Thank you.